# Performance difference between else if( cond ) {} and else { if( cond ) {} }

Tags: c++, performance, conditional-statements

I was rewriting some of my old code today to optimize it and make it slightly more legible (as some of it was pretty shoddily annotated) and I came up wondering if there was any technical performance difference between these blocks of code:

```
if( cond1 )
{
     // Do something.
}
else if( cond2 )
{
     // Do something else.
}
```

And:

```
if( cond1 )
{
     // Do something.
}
else 
{
     if( cond2 )
     {
          // Do something else.
     }
}
```

I reasoned to myself that there should be no performance cost since there should be the same number of comparisons made, but I was just curious as to whether there was something I've overlooked.

Comment: No difference at all. I'd be surprised if that difference even got past syntax analysis, let alone it causing a difference during code generation.

Comment: @john Good point about parsing. For boosting up code generation, I can imagine a compiler that replaces one-child compound statements with their only child.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's see, then, if there's any difference using a *real compiler*.

The following code:

```
int foo(int a, int b)
{
  if(a)
    return 5;
  else if(b)
    return 2;
  else
    return 56582201;
}

int bar(int a, int b)
{
  if(a)
    return 5;
  else
  {
    if(b)
      return 2;
    else
      return 56582201;
  }
}
```

when compiled with GCC 4.8.0, invoked as `g++ a.cpp -fdump-tree-gimple -c` (that's right, *without optimizations*) gives the following GIMPLE (GCC's internal representation):

```
int foo(int, int) (int a, int b)
{
  int D.2205;

  if (a != 0) goto <D.2203>; else goto <D.2204>;
  <D.2203>:
  D.2205 = 5;
  return D.2205;
  <D.2204>:
  if (b != 0) goto <D.2206>; else goto <D.2207>;
  <D.2206>:
  D.2205 = 2;
  return D.2205;
  <D.2207>:
  D.2205 = 56582201;
  return D.2205;
}


int bar(int, int) (int a, int b)
{
  int D.2211;

  if (a != 0) goto <D.2209>; else goto <D.2210>;
  <D.2209>:
  D.2211 = 5;
  return D.2211;
  <D.2210>:
  if (b != 0) goto <D.2212>; else goto <D.2213>;
  <D.2212>:
  D.2211 = 2;
  return D.2211;
  <D.2213>:
  D.2211 = 56582201;
  return D.2211;
}
```

As you see, the difference is *only* in variable and label names, and these are discarded later on anyway.

Compiling with Clang gives similar results: the LLVM IR is practically the same.

So no, there's no difference, *even if you compile without optimizations*.

Comment: I can't +1 enough for having shown a real, actual, "IRL" proof.

Answer (score 7):

They are exactly the same. The compiler doesn't compile the code exactly as you wrote it. Just because there's a difference in the way you wrote something, it doesn't mean there's a difference in the compiled executable. It is allowed to manipulate it as much as it likes as long as the resulting program behaves as the C++ standard describes. This is known as the as-if rule. Since the two samples of code you gave have exactly the same behaviour according to the standard, the compiler will likely compile them to the same executable.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, not a shred. It is doubtful that any compiler would generate different code for these.

Comment: FWIW, I tried in gcc and it generates exactly the same assembly code for both cases.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the language is concerned these two constructs are identical. The code generated should also be identical.